# clEnqueueWriteImage not stable in executing time

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to do some image processing on Android smartphone. When I try to read yuv using clEnqueueWriteImage, sometimes it takes me 1ms but sometimes 20ms. `gray_data` is a 640x480 size 1-dimensional uchar array. I can't figure out where's is the problem. Could you help me with that? Thanks.

```
size_t origin[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
size_t region[3] = { 640, 480, 1 };
clImageFormat.image_channel_order = CL_R;
clImageFormat.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNORM_INT8;
m_clOrigin = clCreateImage2D(m_pclConfig.context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, &clImageFormat, 640, 480, 0, NULL, &ret);
ret = clEnqueueWriteImage(m_pclConfig.queue, m_clOrigin, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, (void *)gray_data, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are calling clFinish before measuring time.

Comment: Yes, I called clFinish(m_pclConfig.queue) after finishing this function. But still I always got various results.

Comment: Can you try after removing CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PT flag

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but not working neither. By the way, I have tested the time cost also by cl_event and gettimeofday and I got the same results. So this should not be a mistake of time measuring.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I don't think the OpenCL specification makes any guarantees about execution time, which means the behavior is implementation-defined. If this is something that you need fast access to, you can try copying it earlier and keeping it loaded until you actually need it, but otherwise there's not much you can do.